# Count the number of sqrt and 4th powers in a function

Tags: functions, counting

This is a simple and short question. I have a function which contains a certain number of square roots and 4th powers, lets take this one:

```
f=Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] Sqrt[z + 2] b^4 + c^3 + d^4
```

I want to be able to count the number of occurrences of the square roots (3) and the number of occurences of the 4th power (2). I think it should be possible to use `Count` for this, but I can't figure out how. I have tried

```
Count[f,_Sqrt,Infinity]
```

and

```
Count[f, Power[4, _], {0, Infinity}]
```

but both don't seem to work. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at `FullForm[f]`; sqrt would be matched by `Power[_, Rational[1, 2]]` for instance.

Comment: As suggested by @b.gatessucks,you should check the `FullForm` of this expression first. Besides, patterns of specified types includes `_Integer`,`_Real`,`_Complex`,`_List`,`_Symbol` and the general `_head`, where `head` is returned by `Head`. So there is no `_Sqrt` but `_Power`,because `Head[Sqrt[x]]` returns `Power`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments suggest, look at the `FullForm` and see what the pattern is that you need to match. For the requested patterns of `Sqrt` and 4th power, `Rational[1, 2]` and `Power[__, 4]` will do:

```
f = Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] Sqrt[z + 2] b^4 + c^3 + d^4 + e^3; 
Count[f, Power[__, Rational[1, 2]], Infinity]
Count[f, Power[__, 4], Infinity]
```

These give the expected counts 3 and 2. The `Infinity` option tells `Count` to look at all levels and the double slash `__` matches any sequence of one or more characters (which will be raised to the designated power).

As Stefan points out, you could count the two patterns simultaneously

```
Count[f, Power[__, Rational[1, 2]] | Power[__, 4], Infinity]
```

to get a count of all the Sqrt's and the 4th powers (in this case 5). Thanks also to Szabolcs.

Comment: why not Count[f, Power[_, Rational[1, 2]] | Power[_, 4], {0, Infinity}]?

Comment: Nice, thanks! A small follow-up: how does `{0, Infinity}` differ from just `Infinity`? Because if I use for example `Count[Sec[x], Sec[__],..]` mathematica returns 0 if I only use `Infinity`, but 1 if I use the `{0,Infinity}'

Comment: @Michiel, {0,Infinity} looks at levels 0 to Infinity, while just `Infinity` looks at levels 1 to Infinity. I guess the choice is whether you expect to see anything in the Head.

Comment: @bills sorry did just realise, that the underscore etc. is formatted away. totally forgot that this is the case with comments. so mea culpa.

Comment: I agree with Stefan, the pattern should be `Power[__, Rational[1, 2]]`. What if you have `f = Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] Sqrt[z + 2] b^4 + c^3 + d^4 + e^3 + 1/2;`?